# Count of relations $ R \subseteq \Bbb N \times \Bbb N $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $ A \subseteq \Bbb N$ . How many binary relations $ R \subseteq A \times A $  are there?

I know that when  $ A \subset \Bbb N$ then the result for is $ 2^{|A \times A|} $. But what if $ A = \Bbb N $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the same, but can be simplified to 
$$2^{|\mathbb N\times\mathbb N|}= 2^{|\mathbb N|}=|\mathbb R|$$